# Update Height of UIImageview on scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollviewdelegate, contentoffset

I've got an `UIImageView` and in the same view I've got an `UITableView`.

I need to get the scroll y movement and the movement should update the height of `UIImageView`.

So if I scroll up the `UITableView`, the `UIImage` should reduce the height, if I scroll it down, the `UIImage` should increment its height.

I've already implemented the methods `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and `scrollViewDidScroll` delegating `<UIScrollviewdelegate>`, I've tried to work with `tableview.contentOffset.y`, but The scroll is less than the reduce of `UIImageView`'s height.

It should be a 1:1, so if I scroll up the `Tableview` for 20px, `UIImage.frame.size.height -= 20`.

EDIT:

Here's the code:

Here I get the starting point of dragging

`- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`
{

`initialframe = _DetailViewTable.contentOffset.y;
    NSLog(@"Will begin dragging %f", initial frame);`

}

In this method I should update the height, but i don't know how to do it.

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{`

```
    NSLog(@"%f",     initialframe-_DetailViewTable.contentOffset.y);`
```

//Here I update UIImageView's height, but it doesn't work properly.

`_imageView.frame = CGRectMake(_imageView.frame.origin.x, , _imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height-(initialframe-_DetailTab));`

}

Comment: Post the actual relationships between the UIImageView and UITableView. I.E. if they are subviews of a container UIView, if they are owned by a single UIViewController or UITableViewController, etc.

Comment: They are part of the same view, 2 separated levels..I've got the uiimageview back and in front I've got the uitableview. Was this the answer that you needed?

Comment: At start height of the imageview and height of the tableview's content are equal?  Or height of the imageview is equal to height of the tableview?  I try imagine image on screen when doing scroll up and down. Height of your imageview have to tend to 0 for scrolling up?

Comment: add your code for reference.....